# Error when importing pyrebase with python3

Tags: python, pyrebase

I tried `pip install pyrebase` but when i import it says 'No module named pyrebase'. I use python3. Also I updated my pip and uninstalled other versions of python but still couldn't resolve the issue. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [Pyrebase4](https://pypi.org/project/Pyrebase4/): `pip install Pyrebase4`.
If it still doesn't work, uninstall pyrebase with `pip uninstall pyrebase`, install [pycryptodome](https://pypi.org/project/pycryptodome/) with `pip install pycryptodome`, and then install Pyrebase4.

Comment: again it didnt work for pycryptodome, i changed the folder name from Crypto to crypto in modules folder and then it worked. just a heads up for anyo there people having the same issue.